# Content tree outputing request

Tags: content-editor

Has anyone seen this? I have Sitecore 8.0 update 7 running and at times(it comes and goes, haven't determined when exactly and why) I see  this request output showing along side with the content tree on the content editor view? I'm not seeing any exceptions on logs that indicate anything useful on this matter
[image]

Comment: Nothing in the console logs either?

Comment: Did you find any thing like sc_debug=1 or sc_prof=1 or sc_trace=1as query string in your URL ?

Comment: no the only parameter is sc_bw=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you might have *Tracing* enabled. This can be configured on a `web.config` level, something like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

See also: [How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973.aspx)

Comment: that was it. I noticed also that if I hit control + F5 it would get rid of that